# Receiving the last notification data on tap

Tags: android, notifications

In my application if there are 3 notification, On tapping of any notification I am getting data of last notification. I am setting number with each notification but If there are multiple notification I get the data of last notification.
Here is my code when I set notification

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = userSetMeetingDate;
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, conferenceHour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, conferenceMinute);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(KEY_CONFERENCE_ID, entity.getId());

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, OnConferenceAlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra(KEY_CONFERENCE_ENTITIY_BUNDLE, bundle);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, entity.getId(), alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

and

```
 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(entity.getName())
            .setContentText(entity.getConfrenceNumber())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(vibrate)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, "Call", pendingIntent)
            //.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit, "Update", pendingIntent)
            .build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    int id = (int) ((long) entity.getId());
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where is notification? This is `alarmManager`!

Comment: Please check, I have edited

Comment: Will the values of `entity.getId()` be different each time?

Comment: Yes it is different all the time

Comment: `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` You are sending broadcast when the notification is clicked. right?

Comment: Yes, Right. So? Am I doing wrong somewhere?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I am facing the same issue.